# iscsi with multiple lun, how linux to connect only selected lun

Tags: linux, storage, iscsi

My 10.1.1.100 have 10 Targets. I'm initially connected to single Target by running

```
iscsiadm --mode node --targetname iqn.2005-06.com.drobo:b800i.1112.id5 --portal 10.1.1.100:3260 --login
```

It only shows one drive connected when I type `fdisk -l` (example /dev/sdb ). The problem is if I restart the iscsid service and again run `fdisk -l`, it shows all the targets. /dev/sdb, /dev/sdc, /dev/sdd ....etc.

How do I avoid this problem? I only want to connect to the target I wanted.

Comment: Which distro and release of Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you have discovered all these targets and they will have been populated into the client database. Depending on your OS, the `node.startup` could be set to automatic in (`/etc/iscsi/iscsid.conf`), so `iscsid` will log into each of them upon initialisation.

To check, run the command:

`iscsiadm -m node`

If this shows all 10 targets and you only want one specific one, then you could delete the targets that you do not want to log into on the client by using the `--op=delete` argument.
Using the target that you want to keep as an example:

`iscsiadm --mode node --targetname iqn.2005-06.com.drobo:b800i.1112.id5 --portal 10.1.1.100:3260 --op=delete`

If you just want to connect to the first available target on that host and then not log into any more, then that is slightly different. In that case you will need to set `node.leading_login` to `Yes` which will login on each iface available until it succeeds then stop.

Answer (score 1):

You can identify loged-in iSCSI targets by their path. In your case it will be -

/dev/disk/by-path/ip-10.1.1.100:3260-iscsi-iqn.2005-06.com.drobo:b800i.1112.id5-lun-0